# Julia Tidier: Group by symbol vector

Tags: julia

I have a vector of symbols, and want to use them in Tidier's group_by macro. However, i assume the macro expects a string arguments which is why this is not working. Is there a way to convert symbols to strings such that tidier can use them.

```
groupvars = [:category, :sub_category, :region]
df_sub = @chain df begin
            Tidier.@group_by(groupvars) 
            Tidier.@mutate(sales = sum(sales), 
                    profit = sum(profit), 
                    cogs = sum(cogs), 
                    discount = sum(discount), 
                    gross_profit = sum(gross_profit))
         end
```

The error is column name :groupvars not found in the dataframe which makes sense as it is converting "groupvars" to a symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Since variables are unquoted symbols in `Tidier` chains it sees *"groupvars"* as a column name.

Using `!!` works though. Boils down to [`@eval()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@eval)

```
using Tidier

groupvars = [:category, :sub_category, :region]

df_sub = 
  @chain df begin
    @group_by(!!groupvars) 
    @mutate(sales = sum(sales), 
            profit = sum(profit), 
            cogs = sum(cogs), 
            discount = sum(discount), 
            gross_profit = sum(gross_profit))
  end
```